# Проверка парсинга чисел при связывании

Tags: wpf, .net, c#

Допустим есть Xaml следующего содержания:

```
<ItemsControl Name="itemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

и в коде есть строки

```
public class Item
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

ObservableCollection<Item> items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
```

При этом при загрузке страницы выполняем

```
itemsControl.ItemsSource = items;
```

При некорректном значении в текстбоксе (например, строке из символов) Item.Value становится равным нулю, но хотелось бы проверять верность введённых значений. Как реализовать подобное поведение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот здесь все довольно подробно описано: [практическое руководство, реализация проверки привязки](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms753962.aspx).